# problems when computers outside the network connect to my localhost

Tags: apache-http-server, ip, wamp, htaccess

I'm trying to let others access the website that I have made. A point of sale system to be exact.  Is it really normal for people outside the network to see broken links?
I'm using apache as a server. Installed through wampserver.
How do I fix this problem? Basically everything is working when I'm just the one who is testing the site. Please comment if you need more details. Thanks

**update**
They can access my localhost using my ip address. They can see the site, but when they click to further links they report an object not found error. I don't know why since I don't see anything like that when I'm the one who is accessing it from localhost itself.
http://localhost/pos

Comment: It's not possible to connect to the `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` address of another computer, you use its IP address. So I'm not sure what your issue is, could you please clarify. I'm reading this as either "they can't connect to the site at all" or, since you mention broken links, "they can reach the site's homepage, but cannot follow links on the page"?

Comment: RE your update: you *cannot* use `http://localhost/` on the site because if they click a `localhost` link they will be trying to connect to thier *own* computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`localhost`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) is a "magic" hostname that always refers to "this computer".

Specifically, it's the standard hostname given to the loopback network interface.

---

If your site includes links that point to `localhost`, then a user of the site will end up trying to connect to thier own computer.

All URLs should be relative if possible (eg, no hostname. So `/images/logo.png` and *not* `http://www.example.com/images/logo.png`). This eliminates the problem, because without a hostname it will use whichever one was already used.

But, if you *have* to make URLs absolute, then the hostname *cannot* be `localhost`. It should be either your domain name or external IP address.

Comment: thanks, that enlightened me. I think I'll just have to change all the links in my site then. Because I'm using absolute urls on my site.